# How can my add-on interface with Firefox Reader View?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-reader-view

I did not find any references to Reader View in any of the SDK APIs listed in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons). In particular, I want to enter Reader View automatically, on page load, as long as a toggle button in my add-on is checked. How can I send this message to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter reader view, all you have to do is change the tab's URL to `about:reader?url={siteURL}`, where `{siteURL}` would be replaced with the URL to the page you want the reader to display.